# Not Counting Properly "signups"

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
select date_format(payout.date, '%m/%d/%Y') as Date,
    (select commission.PAYOUTID from commission
    where commission.status <> "reversed"
    and commission.payoutid = payout.payoutid
    group by commission.payoutid) 
    as PayoutID, 

    convert(payout.acctid,char) as Account,
    payout.total_amount as Commission,

   (select count(commission_tracker.CAMPAIGNID) as 'Signups' from 
   commission_tracker
   where commission_tracker.COMMISSIONTRACKERID = PayoutID) 
   as Signups,
```

1. this last nest above is where the issue is. It will not count
   properly.
2. I cannot seem to get it to return the correct number of sign ups
   because of possibly formatting.
3. any help would be appreciated

   ```
   (select count(account.ACCTID) as 'Dupes' from account
      where account.type = 'customer_duplicate'
      and account.acctid = Signups) 
   as Dupes

   from payout
   where payout.payout_method = 'paypal'
   and payout.payout_status = 'processing'
   order by Commission desc
   ```

Comment: If you format your query properly it will become much easier to find the problem.

Comment: Hello, honestly not really sure what a better way to format this is. I am self taught SQL over the past few weeks. Any suggestions? I think it could be the grouping in the first nest but not sure.

Comment: Are you trying to use the calculated, aliased column "PayoutID" in another subquery for a column in the same select statement? Not only that, it appears you have a PayoutID column in the table already. Which is probably why the count won't return anything... Try running your subquery on it's own to debug.

Comment: So each Payout ID has a # of sign ups. I created the first nest to call in a table that I need to get from the payout table to the number of sign ups in the commission tracker table. if that makes sense.

Comment: @sypher5 - could you describe your tables and how / if they relate?  I'm having problems understanding your data model when trying to update my answer.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The left joins worked. There are relationships but of the 4 tables one is just added in to get important data to the other important data. So: T1 relates to T2 (no data needed table) related to T4 (lots of data needed by T1) relates to T4 (data needed for T3 as pertaining to T1) sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid select 1, (select...), (select...), etc... from table.  This nesting never functions well.  Best to use sum(case when truecondition then 1 else 0 end)

```
 select sum(case when  account.type = 'customer_duplicate'
              and account.acctid = 'Signups' then 1 else 0 end) as fieldname
from payout
where payout.payout_method = 'paypal'
and payout.payout_status = 'processing'
```

In your self learning file, put never use a subselect in a select line as a good rule.  Subselects are great in the from clause, horrible in the select line

Just an edit...remember that a sum() in this case will require a group by if you have other fields

```
select 
date_format(payout.date, '%m/%d/%Y') as Date,
sum(case when  account.type = 'customer_duplicate'
              and account.acctid = 'Signups' then 1 else 0 end) as fieldname
from payout
where payout.payout_method = 'paypal'
and payout.payout_status = 'processing'
group by date
```

Bottom group by will group your results by date.  If you wanted to show results grouped by date,salesman_name then you will need to group by the salesman_name as well.

Comment: I see, the account.type is a different table than the payout table and actually relates to the commission_tracker table. I am trying to see what signups in the commission_tracker table have been marked as duplicates. and then seeing how many duplicates are in the PayoutID. Also the commission_tracker just has total sign ups to the Payout but they have no direct relationship i need to throw in a table that is fairly useless besides the relationship

Comment: Heh, so you are randomly relating data with no keys?

Comment: uhm no, they have relationships but the structure of the relational database seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following code and see if it gets you closer to what you're looking for? It uses joins instead of what you've done.

```
SELECT Date_format(t0a.date, '%m/%d/%Y')                          AS Date, 
       t0b.payoutid                                               AS PayoutID, 
       TO_CHAR(t0a.acctid)                                        AS Account, 
       t0a.total_amount                                           AS Commission,
       count(t0c.campaignid)                                      AS Signups
FROM   payout t0a
JOIN   commission t0b
ON     t0a.payoutid = t0b.payoutid
JOIN   commission_tracker t0c
ON     t0a.payoutid = t0c.commissiontrackerid
WHERE  t0a.payout_method = 'paypal' 
       AND t0a.payout_status = 'processing'
       AND t0b.status <> 'reversed'
GROUP  BY Date_format(t0a.date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
       t0b.payoutid,                                  
       TO_CHAR(t0a.acctid),
       t0a.total_amount
```

I wasn't able to incorporate the 'Dupes' field you're looking to create, because it doesn't make sense to me. How can account.acctid = signups? I'm talking about this bit of your code:

```
(select count(account.ACCTID) as 'Dupes' from account
where account.type = 'customer_duplicate'
and account.acctid = Signups) as Dupes
```

Comment: Hi, I gave it a shot but it returns no rows. No errors but no rows.

Comment: That most likely means that one of the joins doesn't make sense. For example, does it make sense to join on payoutid = commissiontrackerid? Try to look at the ON statements in the query I wrote and see if what you're joining on makes sense. The bigger picture here is to try to use joins instead of those subqueries in the select clause.

Comment: I actually got this to work. I believe i got the duplicates correct to. They are most likely to return 0. It works quickly and efficiently. I was told left joins would not work in this case but im glad they did. I would like to add a t3m of payouts to this as well.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work. I think the big takeaway here is that using multiple joins like in the code I posted is often a good idea. Joins tend to be efficient and it also makes the code more readable. From there it becomes easier to wrap your head around how to use the aggregate functions (e.g. sum, count, average, etc).